# if ! mkdir -p $APPLICATION_DIRECTORY/conf

Tags: linux, shell, sh, ksh

Could anyone tell me what does the following shell command do?

```
if ! mkdir -p $APPLICATION_DIRECTORY/conf
```

Comment: Take a look at the manual: `man mkdir`. There you'll find everything you need to know about this command.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/ is useful for "what does this simple command do?" questions. See [its full explanation](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=if+%21+mkdir+-p%3B+then+true%3B+else+false%3B+fi) of a syntactically-complete command built around your fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mkdir -p "$APPLICATION_DIRECTORY/conf"` attempts to make the named directory, creating any missing parent directories along the way. Like every command, it has an integer exit status, where 0 indicates the directory was successfully created and a non-zero value indicates an error of some kind.

The `if` command tests the exit status of its command, rather than a boolean value as in most other programming languages. The `!` operator negates the exit status: a non-zero exit status is converted to 0, and the exit status 0 is converted to 1.

In other words,

```
if ! mkdir -p "$APPLICATION_DIRECTORY/conf"; then
  echo "There was an error creating the directory"
else
  echo "The directory was successfully created"
fi
```

Comment: Thank You, your answer is very  helpful . :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the direct logic ( more  understandable ) : if mkdir -p ...

example :

```
if mkdir -p "$APPLICATION_DIRECTORY/conf"; then 
   echo "The directory was successfully created"
else 
   echo "There was an error creating the directory"
fi
```